# MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails appears to be empty

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I have an app that I wrote to upload images to my server, which worked great on a droidx running android 2.3.4 and two different simulators running android 4.0.3. However, when I try to run it on an Asus ee Pad Transformer (running 4.0.3), it always tells me that there are 0 items in MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    null,
    null,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
Log.d("Info","There are " + cursor.getCount() + " items");
```

There should be 6 showing up, 5 from the camera and 1 that I downloaded off the internet. Earlier code that just gets images rather than thumbnails tells me that there are 5 images from the camera, so I know that code is working.

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
    cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    "Camera",
    null,null);
Log.d("Info","There are " + cursor.getCount() + " images");
```

These images all show up when I open the gallery app. I've also tried clearing the Media Storage app and rebooting the device to see if that would help, but it didn't. At this point, I'm very confused, especially since this exact same code worked on the phone and simulators.

Comment: same here with my Nexus S, have any clue how to solve it?

Comment: @shem I posted the code I wound up using as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, found it.
When you have the image id you get get it's thumbnail using:

```
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), imageID, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
```

this will return the Bitmap **without** loading the full image.

Comment: Bear in mind this call will block if the bitmap is not available, until it is generated.

Comment: Also, if generation fails, the returned bitmap will be null with no explanation.

Comment: How do you get imageID?

Answer (score 0):

I created a utilities class that will create and return the thumbnails for images and videos if you pass it the uri for the image / video you want to get.

```
package Utilities;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class AndroidUtils 
{
    public static final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 128;
    public static Bitmap GetImagePreview(String uri)
    {
        return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri), THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE);
    }

    public static Bitmap GetVideoPreview(String uri)
    {
        return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(uri, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's work, but are you sure it's getting the right thumbnail and not creating one from original photo? cause it's look like it doing it very slow and with lot of memory

Comment: @shem If I understand the documentation correctly, it's creating a new thumbnail for every image / video. I wrote this code nearly a year ago so it's difficult to remember for sure. Here's a link to the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the BitmapFactory.decodeFile is accessing the original image / video. It's definitely got problems (like it shouldn't be needed in the first place imo) but it's the only thing I've found that works consistantly

Comment: look at my answer, found a way to load it without loading the original file